# How to replace flatMap and mergeMap in rxjs 6.4.0 Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have an interceptor in my Angular 7 app that makes a request to get the token before re-issuing the request. If multiple requests come in at once then they will all make a request to get the token. To avoid that I share an observable so that the result for getting the token is shared and that only one request is made to get the token.

I create the shared observable as follows

```
this.authService.sharedToken =   this.authService.getToken().pipe(share());
```

Then I make the request

```
 return auth.sharedToken.flatMap((res) => {

     auth.saveTokenToLocalStorage(res);
     return this.getRequestWithAuthentication(request, next, auth);

 }).catch(function (err) {// I handle errors here
 }
```

The problem is that flatMap is deprecated and replacing it with mergeMap won't work either. It seems mergeMap is a standalone function right now. So how can I get the code above to work.

I am using  rxjs 6.4.0 
and Angular 7.2.4

Thanks.

EDIT:

using the new pipe approach I have the following:

```
  return auth.sharedToken.pipe(
            mergeMap((res) => {

                auth.saveTokenToLocalStorage(res);
                return this.getRequestWithAuthentication(request, next, auth);
            }), catchError(function (err) {
                console.log("failed to get token")
                return EMPTY;
            }));
```

I cannot get the "failed to get token" to print when the request fails. I do more error handling there, so I need some code to be triggered when the request fails.

Comment: How does `getRequestWithAuthentication` throw an error? Can you share the code.

Comment: In the first code snippet above you can see how I can catch errors. The method you mentioned just calls  return next.handle(req);. However, I can tell if the error is due to the authentication request or from making the actual request. Based on which caused the error i do something different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With *RxJS 5.5* the new **pipe** operator syntax was introduced. In *RxJS 6.0* it became **mandatory** to use over the old syntax.
So you will have to replace your code by

```
.pipe(
    mergeMap(...)
)
```

Comment: If I do it this way.. how do I handle exceptions?      return auth.sharedToken.pipe(
                mergeMap((res) => {
                    gotToken = true;
                    console.log('got token')
                    auth.saveTokenToLocalStorage(res);
                    return this.getRequestWithAuthentication(request, next, auth);
            }));

Comment: you might have to pipe the catchError directly on your nested observable, hence this.getRequestWithAuthentication(request, next, auth).pipe(catchError...)

Comment: This now gets marked as deprecated too, and I can't find any replacement for  it.